# How to make a path follow the serie step in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts, path

I am working with highcharts and I have a serie that uses userOptions step :'right'. This serie builds a path (serie.userOptions.pathList), which I would like to follow the parent. I am unable to find an attribute to change it.

I have tried finding an answer in the highcharts documentation but with no luck so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Could you please specify your question? You can base on the following demo if you want: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xeabzty6/